# Page change its theme on redirect. I don't want to change

Tags: c#, asp.net

Kindly Help What should i do. My Theme is changed when page redirects
Here is ASP.NET Code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dvLeft"></div>
    <div id="dvRight"></div>
    <div id="dvMiddle"></div>
    <div id="dvBottom">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTheme" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem >FirstTheme</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>SecondTheme</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>ThirdTheme</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</form>
```

And Here is C# Code:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request["ddlTheme"] != null)
    {
        string theme = Request["ddlTheme"].ToString();
        Page.Theme = theme;
    }
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Comment: What theme is changed can you explain in detail

Comment: How the redirect happens? The dropdown lilst Autopostback is true.. So when you select value in it, it will post back the form with the value selected in it.. and "PreInit" is getting that value from the Request Object and changes the theme of the page. What is your requirement here?

Comment: Thanks PRABA.. When i change my theme through drop down then it changes on post back But when i refresh my page the default (First Theme) appear. But i want to make my theme static that when i refresh page theme shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya ..

Comment: I can't understand your requirement. while refreshing your page the default first theme appear. then what you mean by static theme when you refresh your page???

Comment: When the user selects the theme, the page is posted back to the server and you change the theme of the page. But the url is still pointing to the same page as the original so when you refresh the original page is returned.

Comment: If the user is to have the same theme afterwards then save the theme in a session variable and every time tge user requests any page, check tge session variable and get the theme from it. Then serve the page with that theme. You may use a cookie instead if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you set selected theme value in the `PreRender` event handler instead of `PreInit` because of the way [ASPX page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#Anchor_1) works.

Below is revised version from your original code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dvLeft"></div>
    <div id="dvRight"></div>
    <div id="dvMiddle"></div>
    <div id="dvBottom">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTheme" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTheme_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="FirstTheme">FirstTheme</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="SecondTheme">SecondTheme</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ThirdTheme">ThirdTheme</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</form>

protected void ddlTheme_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // save value into a session variable
    Session["SelectedTheme"] = ddlTheme.SelectedValue;
}

protected void PreRender()
{
    // works when page reloads
    if (Session["SelectedTheme"] != null){
        Page.Theme = Session["SelectedTheme"].ToString();
    }
    // following line works on postback only
    //Page.Theme = ddlTheme.SelectedValue;
}
```

Update

My original suggestion would only work on postback because when the page reloads, a new page life cycle begins and the selected value from the drop down list would be lost.

However, there's a way to persist the change, which is to use session. To do this, you will attach a new event handler `OnSelectedIndexChanged` where you can save the selected value into a session variable. Then read this value from session after page reloads. See the added code snippet above.

Comment: This will not work because on a refresh the `ddlTheme` will not have the value the user selected previously. See my comment to ops question.